# using custom java script in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have a code that is just basically showing stars i want that to be added to my wordpress website i  have successful uploaded and linked the css and js files in header.php and when i run any page it is infact loading the files i know due to security concerns wordpress wont let you add script in its editor what is the solution? here's my html and js code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>RateYo - Scratchpad</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.rateyo.min.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div>
      <div id="rateYo1" style="margin: 10px"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.rateyo.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function () {

        $("#rateYo1").rateYo({
          rating: 3.5,
          readOnly: true
        });
      });


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add anything you like via hooks.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_scripts', 500 );
function my_custom_scripts() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($, document, undefined) {
            // Your custom code goes here.
        }(jQuery, document))
    </script><?php
}
```

Alternatively you could add it to the head as well using:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_custom_scripts', 500 );
```

Comment: where do u write this hook? like any specific file?

Comment: The above code can be added to either your themes functions.php file or to a custom plugin where you add all your custom code. Basically anywhere you would typically add custom PHP for your WP site.